# In Chrome I cannot set the value of a <select> not yet appended to the document to an empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

Chrome:

[image: Imgur]

Firefox:

[image: Imgur]

As you can see in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silviubogan/1f744g3n/), tested on Chrome 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 15.04, when you set the value of a `<select>` already appended to the document, the value is set even if it is not present in the options inside the `<select>`. This is the behavior I like and I expect.

If we create a `<select>` and set its value to something that does not exist in its options, before appending it to the document, and then we append it to the document, we see that the selected value is the first `<option>` inside it regardless of the value we set.

I think this is a Chromium bug because I tested this in Firefox 41.0.1 on Ubuntu 15.04 and the first behavior, the one I like, is present in both cases. Can you give me a link to this Chromium bug, if it is already reported? Can you help me avoid this issue considering that I have a function that must return a jQuery `<select>` element not yet appended to the document but with its value set to an empty string?

Thank you very much! `:-)`

---

**Update:** I opened [this Chromium issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=542134).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is rather a Firefox bug than Chrome bug (and FYI, IE render it like Chrome).

This is not an `.append` matter, but an existing (or not) option matter.

You are telling the `<select>` to display as `:selected` a non existing option : `<option val=""></option>` doesn't exist.

---

You can have more informations about this in the console with this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/289e5hnw/).

Your `select` object is well created, and there is only one `option`, `.val()` will always be `B`. (you can show more info for the object and scroll to "value" to see for both `.val("B")` and `.val("")`. Anyway, if you try to alert `.val()` when you previously set `.val("")`, it returns `null`

---

One solution would be to `.append()` an empty `option` to the `select`:

```
$("<select>")
    .append("<option val=''></option>")
    .append("<option val='B'>B</option>")
    .val("")
    .appendTo("body");
```

Please see this [new Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24os3nr3/)

---

Update:
As you were just asking for a known report, [here is a link](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8813) to a reported bug similar to yours on jQuery.com. It is a bit Out to Date, but the behavior is the same, and you got some additional info.

Answer (score 0):

**update:**
the behavior really is strange. but I don't know how it is supposed to be.

seems like in chrome the `select` can't hold a value while it's not in the `DOM`.
in firefox the `select` is maybe pre-rendered and thus can hold a value.

but that's just my assumption.

to avoid this problem I just would "physically" add an "no-value" or "null" `option`:

```
$("<select>")
    .append("<option val=''></option>")
    .append("<option val='B'>B</option>")
    .val("")
    .appendTo("body")
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p3boza33/2/

Comment: Thank you for your answer `:-)` but, as I mentioned in the question, "I have a function that must return a jQuery `<select>` element not yet appended to the document but with its value set to an empty string".

Comment: @silviubogan i know, but i don't know what difference it would make in your case. i post an update to my answer in a sec.